# Extra space above and below Android Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-webview, android-imageview

I am downloading a bitmap from a website and then displaying it in my application. Whenever I download this image and set it into an ImageView, there is always a lot of extra space above or below the actual image. This extra space is part of the ImageView and is only there after I set the ImageBitmap to the downloaded bitmap.
So, this is making me think that the extra space is somehow part of the bitmap.
However, when I download the same image in a Webview, there is no extra space.

If you have any ideas on why this could be happening, please let me know! Let me know if you need any more information, thanks.

Edit: Here's my code getting the bitmap:

```
    InputStream in = null;
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = 1;
    try{
        in = openHttpConnection(_url);
        if (in != null)
        {
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putParcelable("bitmap", bit);
            msg.setData(b);
            in.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    _handle.sendMessage(msg);
```

And this is what I use to then for the ImageView, I get the bitmap from the code above and:

```
imageV.setImageBitmap(comic);
```

Edit 2:
After trying this with some other images from different website, I've found that this white space is not always there. Given that, and there's probably not anything wrong with the code, are there any suggestions on removing this extra space since it doesn't show up in the actual image online nor in a webview?

Answer (score 0):

imageSize = din.readInt();

imageName = din.readUTF();

byte b[] = new byte[imageSize];
din.readFully(b);

bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b,0,b.length);

//This works for me....
//din is DataInputStream object.